# How to output a table with values from a table, alongside repeated lookup id's of a reference table (in Pentaho PDI and SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Consider, I have table_A, like:

**table_A**

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
| code_1 | code_2 | code_3 | qty |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|   0.5  |   0.6  |   0.2  |  3  |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|   0.8  |   1.2  |   3.2  |  4  |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|   3.0  |   2.2  |   0.4  |  7  |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
```

and a reference_table, like:

**reference_table**

```
+--------+--------+
|   id   | code   |
+--------+--------+
|    1   | code_1 |
+--------+--------+
|    2   | code_2 |
+--------+--------+
|    3   | code_3 |
+--------+--------+
```

Now, I would like to get the output like:

**output_table**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|   id   |  value |   qty  |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    1   |   0.5  |    3   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    2   |   0.6  |    3   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    3   |   0.2  |    3   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    1   |   0.8  |    4   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    2   |   1.2  |    4   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    3   |   3.2  |    4   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    1   |   3.0  |    7   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    2   |   2.2  |    7   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|    3   |   0.4  |    7   |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

**NB:-** The reference table is in a MySQL database, and the table_A is in a MSSQL database. I use Pentaho PDI to get data from both the tables (in different databases, via the "Table Input" step).

How can the **output_table** be obtained in **Pentaho PDI - Spoon (ETL)**?

Also, how is this done in **SQL** (if both the tables were in the same **MSSQL** database)?

***Thanks in advance***  :)

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server - they are totally different products.

Comment: This site prefers formatted text for data and code (i.e. not images). Ideally as DDL/DML statements that can be copy and pasted out.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DaleK, I've tried doing "full outer join" for the tables (in Pentaho), but wasn't quite sure how to proceed, being an amateur.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags. When you replace your images with text, please retag the RDBMS you are actually using, and *only* the RDBMS you are actually using.

Comment: @Larnu, Thanks. But the "reference_table" is in a MySQL database, whearas the "table_A" is in a MSSQL database. I use Pentaho PDI for joining the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use a lateral join -- i.e. the keyword `apply`:

```
select r.id, v.value, a.qty
from table_A a cross apply
     (values ('code_1', a.code_1), ('code_2', a.code_2), ('code_3', a.code_3)
     ) v(code, value) join
     reference r
     on r.code = v.code;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, Gordon. But in my case, I have the table_A in MSSQL server and reference_table in MySQL. I extract data from both tables with ETL. I would also prefer a transformation that could yield the output_table from both the tables (table_A and reference_table).

Comment: @Rohith . . . Just create a link in SQL Server to the MySQL table and use this query.